# can an S corporation pay its owner as a consultant, so owner can use schedule C deductions?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, s-corporation

I'm a consultant with an S corp.
If my S-corp pays me as a consultant, so that the K-1 is 0 income, then can I file 1040 schedule C in order to get deductions like:
- use of home office, and
- health insurance
- mileage deduction